# Create interlaced image using phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, jpeg

So, until now I can take screenshots, create images and save them, but I need those to be interlaced.. how can I do it ? It is really important because I do not want to loose the quality of my jpg's by creating new ones interlaced using some separated php script for example..

It should be so simple as:

```
page.render('sites/teste/images/o'+i+'.jpg', {format: 'jpg', quality: '100', interlaced: '1'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's no possible with PhantomJS alone, because the only additional option that is passed to the actual rendering function is the image quality ([source](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/2.0.0/src/webpage.cpp#L924-L941)).

You can render a lossless png with PhantomJS and convert it to an interlaced jpg with your favorite tools.

Comment: This will be an automated process, and rendering png's and then converting to jpg will use to much cpu.. if I render png first some of them reach 16 mb files..

Comment: PhantomJS is open source. Change it and build it. If it works well then you can contribute back by creating a pull request